# What capabilities does my Home Connect appliance provide in the developer SDK?

Tags: smart-home, kitchen-appliances, home-connect

The smart household appliances that can be controlled via [Home Connect](http://www.home-connect.com/de/en) can also be accessed via a developer SDK provided by the Home Connect Service provider. How can I find out what I will be able to do with a prospective oven, e.g. a [Siemens iQ700 CM678G4S6B](http://www.siemens-home.bsh-group.com/uk/productlist/cooking/microwaves/built-in-ovens-with-microwave/CM678G4S6B?breadcrumb=ovens), by using the SDK provided by the developer of the service?

I found [this information in the SDK developer information](https://developer.home-connect.com/?q=docs/oven/supported_programs_and_options), detailing that in general I can get information about several heating modes and a pizza mode. Will I be able to use those functions with the oven and how detailed will the information about the oven status be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, it appears that the SDK [is still in beta](https://developer.home-connect.com/).  However, you can apply for it and get a feel for how it will work with their simulator.

When it does finally come out, you should be able to do anything with it that you are able to do with the [Home Connect](http://www.home-connect.com/de/en/) application.  As a matter of fact, the Home Connect SDK is called (right in their banner) Home Connect for Developers.

In other words, anything you are able to do with the Home Connect application, you should also be able to do, with sufficient coding, as a developer with the SDK.